# Code Build logs me out of application (IIS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, iis-7

I have a peculiar problem that just started happening out of the blue.

I will build my application using an IDE, navigate to it in the web browser, and log in.

Log in uses FormsAuthentication to set a cookie.

I then found a bug so I fixed it and rebuild my application.

When i refresh the page I navigated to, it had logged me out of the application and ask to log back in again. (clears my cache or something . . . not sure, HELP!!)

Why is this happening, it never happened before and all of a sudden it started happening.

The application is hosted though IIS 7.

Comment: What are you using for authentication?  Why did you add mono to the tags if it's running on IIS?  What version of the framework?

Comment: We develop in Mono / Xamarin Studio 4. Host the site in IIS. Even though I know that MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio uses windows dll's. Its a standard Session type authentication. User Logs on and a new session gets created. So typically the session gets cleared when the dll's gets updated. Using .net 4 to compile in Xamarin Studio.

Comment: First, there's no such thing as a "standard session type authentication".  Authentication and Session have nothing to do with each other, unless you are stupidly using session to control your authentication (session is insecure, so using session is, by definition also insecure).  Authentication is either cookie based (ie, FormsAuthentication tickets) or it's based on Headers (as in basic authentication) or it's based on Windows Authentication, none of which have anything to do with session.

Comment: Second, if you are using session, when you rebuild your DLL's, then the app pool gets recycled (because it has to restart the application with your new code), and any session that's currently in place will be lost (sessions are stored in memory).  Sessions can be lost at any time because the app pool can be lost at any time (another reason not to base your authentication on session).  For instance, IIS can decide to recycle the app pool if it thinks memory is too fragmented or other possible reasons.  If you use session, you have to expect this and rebuild it if necessary.

Comment: My Apologies, I had another look at our code. Was not very familiar with our authentication and how it was done. We save some user details in a session e.g. email address etc. Once this has been done we use FormsAuthentication, so we are using cookies. I will update the question so it is more accurate.

Comment: Is it possible that if those user details that are stored in session are not present (ie the session has been lost) then there is code that forces a logout?  It's really easy to prove that session has nothing to do with logging you out. Just create a new default app from a template, using standard authentication.. Create an account and log in, then recycle your app pool and refresh your page... you should still be logged in.  So, if that's the case, then obviously there is user code that's causing the issue.

Comment: Well this is very correct indeed. I logged in, went to IIS, Recycled the APP Pool connected to the Site, and that logged me out asking to log back in. There is code that checks if a userID is present in a current session, if not go to the log in page.

Comment: Well, that's the problem.  If it didn't use to do this, then someone added that code recently.  If it wasn't added recently, then it has always done this and you just never noticed before.  In any event, this is poor practice.  Session should be rebuilt if lost, not forcing the user to login again.  Because session can be lost for any number of reasons, all of which are valid runtime environments.  You don't want to force users to login again just because you recycle the app pool.

Comment: Thank you for your help, and you are correct, this is bad practice and confirmed another long standing issue we have with our CI server that Kicks users out when deployment has completed. We will need to have a look at rebuilding those user sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So solved my problem by setting `Session Sate Mode Settings` and using the `State Server` option. Just default settings did it for me.